# Hibernate domain object validation error redundant ,why?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I am using Hibernate on Grails.

When I have field validation error, the exception message contains redundant message.

e.g

> Provided id of the wrong type for class ad.Client. Expected: class java.lang.String, got class java.lang.Long; nested exception is org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class org.ad.Client. Expected: class java.lang.String, got class java.lang.Long

when I have many field erros, I got a lot of unexpected redundant messages, why is this happening?

Comment: Can you show us what code you are using to print the error messages?

Comment: @th3morg `try{ new Client(params).save(failOnError:true); }catch(Exception ex){println ex.getMessage();}`

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the way exceptions wrap each other, and how getMessage() works.  Stack traces and exception messages of any kind often have *some* redundant information.  Better too much than not enough :) It shouldn't really be an issue as this is for you, the developer.  This isn't something you show externally, and not something to spend time on trying to improve.